# Getting username from flask session into gunicorn log

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Is there a way to include a value from the flask session (like username in this case) into the access log of gunicorn?

I know that I can include custom values with a filter like this:

```py
class UserFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.username = "TestUser"
        return True
```

But as soon as I try to get the value for `record.username` from the session I get:

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing
> for information about how to avoid this problem.